# Let $G$ be a group, $H, K \le G$. Under what conditions does $G/H \cong G/K \Rightarrow H \cong K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, quotient-group

> Let $G$ be a group, $H, K \le G$. Under what conditions does $G/H \cong G/K \Rightarrow H \cong K$?

I believe there was a condition that could be simply stated under which it was true. Maybe having to do something with split exact sequences?

Comment: One sufficient condition is that $H$ and $K$ are conjugate under $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any useful sufficient conditions other than extremely restrictive ones like that $G$ is finite elementary abelian (equivalently, a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space) or cyclic (in which case a subgroup is determined by its index). Consider the following very simple counterexample: $G = C_2 \times C_4$ has two non-isomorphic subgroups $H = C_2 \times C_2, K = 1 \times C_4$ both of whom have quotient $C_2$. This is the smallest finite abelian group which is not elementary abelian or cyclic.

$G$ is also a counterexample to the analogous statement about whether $H \cong K$ implies $G/H \cong G/K$: this time if we take $H = C_2 \times 1$ and $K = 1 \times C_2$, the two subgroups are isomorphic but their quotients are $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$ respectively. Actually this counterexample is [Pontryagin dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) to the previous one.

Comment: Wait a second, how about characteristic subgroups?

Comment: @Jos: consider the Prufer $2$-group $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]/\mathbb{Z}$. It has two non-isomorphic characteristic subgroups of orders $2$ and $4$ generated by $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ (precisely the subgroups of second resp. fourth roots of unity) and the quotient by either of them is isomorphic to the Prufer $2$-group again.